# How to find the maximum area of a rectangle that can be inscribed in an ellipse $4x^2+y^2=4$

Tags: optimization, conic-sections, area, maxima-minima

We choose the point A(x,y) to lie on the ellipse and one of the corners of the rectangle. Let $f$ be the area of the inscribed rectangle. Show that it can be written as: $$f(x)=8x\sqrt{1-x^2}, 0<x<1$$
then find the point A on the ellipse that gives the biggest area

Comment: HI, did you try something ?

Comment: The other vertices of the rectangle will be $(-x,y),(x,-y),(-x,-y)$, I think.

Comment: so you have a rectangle with $$S=(x-(-x))*(y-(-y))=4xy$$ now put $y$ from the ellipse to $S$

Comment: It is not so trivial that the other vertices must be $(-x,y), (x,-y), (-x,-y)$. One way is to compare with the parallelogram inscribed in the circle $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: Agree with aerile: it isn't so trivial. The problem can be solved without calculus if we're allowed to use the (non-trivial) fact that the largest quadrilateral inscribed in a circle is a square. But that might not count as an answer to the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a \cos t, b \sin t)$ be in first quadrant. The area of the rectangle in this quadrant is $ab \sin t \cos t$. The  area of the big rectangle is
$$A=4ab \sin t \cos t=  2ab \sin 2t \implies A_{max}=2ab, ~\text{when}~ 2t =\pi/2$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a non-calculus solution.

Convince yourself that sides of optimum rectangle will be parallel to axes of ellipse (or the coordinate axes) due to symmetry of ellipse. As pointed out in comments, its vertices will be

$$ {(x,y), (-x,y), (-x,-y), (x,-y)} $$

which gives sides $2x$, $2y$ and area $S = 4xy$.

Now consider,

$$ (2x-y)^2 \ge 0 $$
$$ \Rightarrow 4x^2 + y^2 - 4xy \ge 0 $$
$$ \Rightarrow S \le 4x^2 + y^2 = 4 $$

The equality occurs at $2x-y=0$ from which one can find point $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x,y)$ be a vertex of the rectangle.

Thus, by AM-GM $$S=2|x|\cdot2|y|=4|xy|\leq2\cdot\frac{(2|x|)^2+|y|^2}{2}=4.$$
The equality occurs for $2|x|=|y|,$ which says that we got a maximal value.